# Get a list of all pytest node ids using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Do you know if there is a way to collect all pytest node ids (as presented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests)) using the pytest python API ?

I have found the `--collect-only` parameter of pytest, but I can't figure out how to get the output using python ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: the link you provided does not contain any information on node ids.

Comment: @VishalSingh It was just to illustrate how to use a node id with python (under section "Run tests by node ids")

Comment: are you running tests from inside a python script?

Comment: Yes, using the `pytest.main()` function

Comment: `pytest -q --collect-only`

Comment: @hoefling thanks but it just returns an ExitCode, not a node ids list

Comment: Ah, so you want to access them in the code?

Comment: @hoefling Yep :). I would like to get a a python list of all node ids

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access nodeids programmatically, best is to write a small plugin that will store them on test collection. Example:

```
import pytest


class NodeidsCollector:
    def pytest_collection_modifyitems(self, items):
        self.nodeids = [item.nodeid for item in items]


def main():
    collector = NodeidsCollector()
    pytest.main(['--collect-only'], plugins=[collector])
    # use collector.nodeids now
```

If you want to avoid `pytest` output to the terminal, disable the terminal plugin in addition:

```
pytest.main(['--collect-only', '-pno:terminal'], plugins=[collector])
```