# How to call pytest from own python code to collect tests

Tags: python, pytest

I need to write a simple test for CI: every QA test should have an external documentation. After some shell struggles I decided to use pytest.

I need to get a list of collected tests by pytest. There is a `pytest.main()` to execute a pytest, but I don't need to run them, all I need a list of test names.

From shell I can do it like this:

```
pytest-3 --collect-only  -q quality_assurance/|grep '::'
```

output looks like this:

```
quality_assurance/test_test.py::foo
```

But I want it to be more native to Python, without using `subprocess.run` and parsing stdout.

How to get a list of collected pytest tests using pytest as a Python module?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62955267/2650249) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the answer! Thanks!